# create an svg starting from a png

Tags: inkscape, gimp, svg, png

how can i turn this image :

[image: 1]

into an svg to use in blender?
I tried to use gimp to convert in in a black and white image, but then with inkscape I don't know hot to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: this image is copryright, and so if it's for anything other than strictly personal/private/educational use, you won't able to legally use it. I'm answering this question for educational purposes only.

There is no way to directly convert a raster image format into an SVG made from vectors. Two indirect methods exist: either manual tracing/redrawing, or automatic bitmap tracing.

However the sample image is too low resolution, and because of the gradients it's too complex for using anything automated, such as the Trace Bitmap function in Inkscape. So you will either need to redraw it manually using the Pen Tool, or find a vector version of the logo.

You could try to find the original font, and retype the letters. Alternatively tracing letters by hand is possible, but tedious. Sorry no real shortcuts here.

[image]

I notice that someone has already uploaded the letters to [wikimedia commons](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Microsoft_Flight_Simulator_logo.svg), so you may not need to start from scratch, although I notice it's not particualarly good quality.

Comment: i was thinking about setting all the letters in a color only(or grayscale) to reduce to complexity of the image an then using the bitmap trace in inkscape

Comment: @DarioGallo - yeah but the image is too low resolution to trace well.  That's the main problem.